# I need to get the row and column value from a 2d array in C#

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, linq

I'm completely stumped. I've inserted strings in random locations in a 50x50 two dimensional array and I need to filter through the array by the string, locate it's index, and somehow obtain the row/column (or x,y coordinate) from that index. 
I am using C#. I don't feel there is a need to explain the larger program as this is my only hangup.

Should I be using lists instead? I can't use the indexOf method on a 2d array so that doesn't work.

Comment: If you want a simple quadratic-time algorithm, loop through each element of your 2D array with a double-nested for loop and do a string compare, then return the (x,y) value if found.

Comment: check my answer below.

Comment: I appreciate it! I'll check it out now.

Answer (score 0):

**Reference : [Accessing Two-Dimensional Array Elements](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/csharp/csharp_multi_dimensional_arrays.htm)**

```
using System;
    namespace ArrayApplication
    {
       class MyArray
       {
          static void Main(string[] args)
          {
             /* an array with 5 rows and 2 columns*/
             int[,] a = new int[5, 2] {{0,0}, {1,2}, {2,4}, {3,6}, {4,8} };
             int i, j;

             /* output each array element's value */
             for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
             {
                for (j = 0; j < 2; j++)
                {
                   Console.WriteLine("a[{0},{1}] = {2}", i, j, a[i,j]);
                }
             }
             Console.ReadKey();
          }
       }
    }
```

**Output:**

```
    a[0,0]: 0
    a[0,1]: 0
    a[1,0]: 1
    a[1,1]: 2
    a[2,0]: 2
    a[2,1]: 4
    a[3,0]: 3
    a[3,1]: 6
    a[4,0]: 4
    a[4,1]: 8
```

Hope it Helps